# Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'deletePostById' Angular

Tags: angular

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deletePostById')

What's the problem in my code?

HTML

```
<div class="row post" *ngFor="let post of posts">
     <div *ngIf="isAdminIn" ngbDropdown class="float-right" class=" col-md-1">
        <button (click)="deletePost(post.id)">Delete</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
 deletePost(id:number): void {
  this.postService.deletePostById(id).subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('');
  }, error => {
    throwError(error);
  })

}
```

service.ts

```
 deletePostById(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:8080/api/posts/' + id);
  }
```

Comment: Might be useful to show the entire component that contains deletePost. It looks like the postService is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `postService` is undefined. Have you injected it inside of component's constructor?

```
constructor(
  private postService: PostService
) {}
```

??

Comment: Thanks it's working!. I've already declared Post Service but it' wasn't in constructor. Thanks